# How do I debug my native modules in atom electron?

Tags: debugging, native, electron

Using Visual studio I can debug my module in against node but the electron environment does not seem to allow this. I can see that my module has loaded with the matching symbols. My break points become active but it will not break when the my test method is called.
If i set an "int 3" (debug break assembler instruction) it just crashes electron.
Anything I am missing here?

Comment: This must be posdible. anyone doing this?

Comment: Hey Justin, I am having the same issue. Did you have any luck solving this?

Comment: No sorry I have moved on. Maybe it's worth asking someone on the vscode gitter chanel what their work flow is. They use electron